# Spring AOP logging thread method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, aop

Is there any way to implement AOP logging to public method of class that `implements Runnable` and ran by ExecutorService?

Thread class

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FileProcessor implements Runnable {

  private final LinkedBlockingQueue<File> filesQueue;
  private final GiftCertificateMapper certificateMapper;
  private final File errorFolder;
  private static final ReentrantLock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileProcessor.class);

  public FileProcessor(LinkedBlockingQueue<File> filesQueue, GiftCertificateMapper certificateMapper,
      File errorFolder) {
    this.filesQueue = filesQueue;
    this.certificateMapper = certificateMapper;
    this.errorFolder = errorFolder;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    File file = null;
    try {
      while ((file = filesQueue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) != null) {
        processFile(file);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      LOGGER.warn("File thread was interrupted");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error processing file {} \n{}", file.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    }
  }

  public void processFile(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file != null) {
      try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<GiftCertificate> certificates = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(file, GiftCertificate[].class));
        certificateMapper.insertList(certificates);
        file.delete();
      } catch (JsonParseException | UnrecognizedPropertyException | InvalidFormatException | DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        moveFileToErrorFolder(file);
      }
    }
  }

  private void moveFileToErrorFolder(File file) throws IOException {
    try {
      LOCK.lock();
      Files.move(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), getPathForMovingFile(file), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
    } finally {
      LOCK.unlock();
    }
  }

  private Path getPathForMovingFile(File fileForMove) {
    File fileList[] = errorFolder.listFiles();
    int filesWithSameNameCounter = 0;
    if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
      for (File file : fileList) {
        if (file.getName().contains(fileForMove.getName())) {
          filesWithSameNameCounter++;
        }
      }
    }
    return filesWithSameNameCounter > 0 ?
        Paths.get(errorFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "(" + filesWithSameNameCounter + ")" + fileForMove.getName()) :
        Paths.get(errorFolder.getAbsolutePath(), fileForMove.getName());
  }
}
```

Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = "file-processing.logging.enabled",
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = true)
public class FileProcessingLoggingAspect {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileProcessingLoggingAspect.class);

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.epam.esm.processor.FileProcessor.processFile(java.io.File))")
  public void processFilePointcut() {
  }

  @Around("processFilePointcut()")
  public Object logFileProcessing(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
//    File file = (File) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
//    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object object = joinPoint.proceed();
//    long resultTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    LOGGER.info("Processing of file took  milliseconds");
    return object;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show an example of the type of class you'd want to advise. Is that class registered as a Spring bean? What have you tried to make it work? Why hasn't it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis added info, no, it's not registered as a Spring bean

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It won't work if object is not registered as spring bean?

Comment: No, advice is only applied to beans within the Spring Application Context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis editi structure of my application but pointcut on processFile method still not working, but if i change method on run, it works, where can be problem? Can you help please?

Comment: @AlexStepanov , In Spring AOP , internal method calls cannot be intercepted.  In the sample code shared `run()` calls the method `processFile(File file)`. Refer the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)  and plese go through the info section that starts with _Due to the proxy-based nature ..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring AOP , internal method calls cannot be intercepted.

In the code shared , even though the method `processFile()` is public , it gets called from `run()`. This is a self reference / internal method call , which cannot be intercepted.

Details can be read in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within
>   the target object are, by definition, not intercepted. For JDK
>   proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be
>   intercepted

A pointcut expression to intercept all external method calls to a class implementing `Runnable` would be as follows

```
@Around("this(java.lang.Runnable) && within(com.epam.esm.processor..*)")
public Object logFileProcessing(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    try {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
        //log
        System.out.println("****Logged");
    }
}
```

Scoping designator `within()` limits the scope to apply the advice.

The point cut `@Pointcut("execution(* com.epam.esm.processor.FileProcessor.processFile(java.io.File))")` is valid and would work if an external method call happens to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already got and implemented load-time weaving, but ty anyways.